Find the vertices of all the sub-simplexes following Barycentric subdivision
I have a set of K dimension standard basis vectors and the (K-1)-simplex defined over these vectors. I want to divide this simplex into sub-simplexes which partition the original simplex using Barycentric subdivision.
For example when K = 3, the three vertices of the simplex are [1,0,0], [0,1,0] and [0,0,1]. If you subdivide this at the coarsest level using barycentric subdivision you get the following:

Find the mid point of each edge: [1/2, 1/2, 0], [1/2, 0, 1/2],[0, 1/2, 1/2]
Find the barycentric point: [1/3, 1/3, 1/3]

The following list of lists provides all the vertices of each sub-simplex which partitions the original simplex:

[[[1,0,0], [1/2, 1/2, 0] [1/3, 1/3, 1/3]]]
[[[1,0,0], [1/2, 0, 1/2] [1/3, 1/3, 1/3]]]
[[[0,1,0], [1/2, 1/2, 0] [1/3, 1/3, 1/3]]]
[[[0,1,0], [0, 1/2, 1/2] [1/3, 1/3, 1/3]]]
[[[0,0,1], [1/2, 0 ,1/2] [1/3, 1/3, 1/3]]]
[[[0,0,1], [0, 1/2, 1/2] [1/3, 1/3, 1/3]]]

In lower dimensions this is an easy task to do by hand, however I would like to write a function (ideally in python, though I am flexible) that takes the vertices of the original simplex and the level of split and returns the list of lists of each sub-simplex and it's vertices.
I have tried to develop an algorithm that answers this problem, however I get stuck in the logic. Each sub-simplex will contain a vertex on of the (K-1) dimensions, e.g. in this case a point, on the edge and on the face. Therefore I tried a combinatory approach, but couldn't extend it to N dimensions in way that can be programmed into a function.
Is anyone aware of a relevant package (or mathematical software?) that can help answer this question, or on how to write the logic into a python function.

You can try the following:
from itertools import permutations
import numpy as np
from sympy import Rational

k = 2 # dimension of the simplex

fracs = np.c_[[Rational(1, i) for i in range(1, k+2)]]
subdivision = []
for p in permutations(range(k+1)):
    s = np.where(np.tile(p, (k+1, 1)) <= np.c_[:k+1], fracs, 0)
    subdivision.append(s)

for s in subdivision:
    print(*s)

It gives:
[1 0 0] [1/2 1/2 0] [1/3 1/3 1/3]
[1 0 0] [1/2 0 1/2] [1/3 1/3 1/3]
[0 1 0] [1/2 1/2 0] [1/3 1/3 1/3]
[0 0 1] [1/2 0 1/2] [1/3 1/3 1/3]
[0 1 0] [0 1/2 1/2] [1/3 1/3 1/3]
[0 0 1] [0 1/2 1/2] [1/3 1/3 1/3]

The code will work for any k, but since the barycentric subdivision of a k-simplex has (k+1)! simplices of dimension k, it is not practical compute them all for larger values of k.

This works great. In the original question I mentioned that I want to set the level of split, e.g. this is subdividing once. I want to be able to subdivide more times: subdivide each sub-simplex using the same procedure. Is there a straightforward edit to this solution that achieves that?

@JoeEmmens To get the second subdivision of a simplex, you need to subdivide it once and then subdivide each subsimplex. You could apply this recursively to get subdivision of any order. It would not be to complicated to extend the code above to do this. How to do it exactly, will depend on what you want to accomplish. For example, can the baricentric coordinates be given as floats, or do you want to keep them as fractions? Also, again, the number of simplices will grow exponentially, so quickly there will be too many of them to list them all.
